# Empty string in Elasticsearch date field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a date field setup in my mapping like this:

```
"groupsAssignedDate" : {
    "type" : "date",
    "format" : "MM-dd-YYYY"
}
```

In my app, the field groupsAssignedDate is set to the empty string initially. When a group is assigned, a unix timestamp is generated and stored in the field. I'm trying to use elasticsearch's bulk update function to bring in a bunch of documents with a groupsAssignedDate of "" because no groups have been assigned yet. Elasticsearch won't index the docs though. This is in the log file:

```
Failed to parse [groupsAssignedDate]
...
failed to parse date field [], tried both date format [MM-dd-YYYY], and timestamp number
```

It appears elasticsearch supports the JSON null value...do I need to switch my docs from using "" to null or is there some way I can support using the empty string instead?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sounds like you may have answered this yourself. Just using null rather than "" in the date field should work.

If that's an issue, maybe consider this from
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed-setting

The **index.mapping.ignore_malformed** global setting can be set on the index level to allow to ignore malformed content globally across all mapping types (malformed content example is trying to index a string value as a numeric type).

**EDIT**
Edited the URL above to jump to the new information.

**EDIT**
Edited the URL above again to jump to the new information.

Comment: Even I am facing this issue. Where should I set this value?

Comment: Try taking a look at the index settings section half way down this page: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/setup/configuration/

Comment: @Phil Nothing at this link regarding setting ignore_malformed so assuming it has changed? Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: @steven.levey - the info is at the end of the page in the final section here: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-settings - I'll edit the answer

Comment: Link is now found at: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-malformed.html#ignore-malformed-setting