# failed to parse field [datefield] of type [date]

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm trying to index a lot of records but I'm facing some troubles when index `publish_up` field. I mapped that field as date and format by default but 
I get this error:

> Error: 400 {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [publish_up] of type [date]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse field [publish_up] of type [date]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Invalid format: \"2015-02-11 00:00:00\" is malformed at \" 00:00:00\""}},"status":400}

This is how I configure index:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'attachments',
    'body' => [
        'settings' => [ 
            'number_of_shards' => 1,
            'analysis' => [ 
                'analyzer' => [
                    'custom_analizer_texto_sub' => [
                        'type' => 'custom',
                        'tokenizer' => 'keyword',
                        'filter' => ['lowercase']
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ],
        'mappings' => [
            'article' => [
                '_source' => [
                    'enabled' => true
                ],
                'properties' => [
                    'iddoc' => [ 'type' => 'integer'],
                    'publish_up' => [ 'type' => 'date'],//, 'format' => 'YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss'], //Y/m/d H:i:s
                    'textofull' => [ 'type' => 'keyword']
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

And index code (here I get the error):

```
    $params = [
        'index' => 'attachments',
        'type' => 'documentos',
        'id' => $datos->id,
        'body' => [
            'iddoc' => $datos->id,
            'publish_up' => $datos->publish_up,
            'textofull' => $datos->fulltext
        ]
    ];
    $response = $client->index($params);
```

**NOTE:** `$datos->publish_up` has this dateformat `2015-02-11 00:00:00`. I checked [Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-date-format.html) but I can't solve my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your date format is not standard ISO8601 (missing the `T` between the date and the time), you need to add a format in your mapping. You did, but the pattern was wrong, as you used `YYYY` for years instead of `yyyy` and `mm` for months instead of `MM`. Try like this:

```
                'publish_up' => [ 'type' => 'date', 'format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'],
                                                                   ^  ^
                                                                   |  |
                                                               change these
```

Answer (score 0):

A few other causes for this error:

- Elasticsearch automapped some fields like "2021-10-09" establishing the field as a date, then it came upon a `""` which is not a valid date. The solution is to feed it `null` instead, or try the options from https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950434/733092.
- You tried to post a "JSON" document you copied out of MongoDB, but it was actually Mongo's [Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/) format, which represents dates as `{"$date":"2021-10-08T21:46:10.840Z"}`. In this case, just remove the wrapper and save it as `"2021-10-08T21:46:10.840Z"`.